# Commutative property based on integral substraction.

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

I found elementary algebra exercise which I can't resolve. Let algebraic structure $(X,\cdot)$ where $\cdot$ has properties:

$$ 
x\cdot(x\cdot y)=y \\
(y\cdot x)\cdot x=y
$$

How to proof that $\cdot$ is commutative? If $X=\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\cdot n=-m-n$ then it is true and $\cdot$ has expected poroperties.

$$
m\cdot(m\cdot n)=-m-(-m-n)=n\\
(n\cdot m)\cdot m=-(-n-m)-m=n
$$

and

$$
m\cdot n=-m-n=-n-m=n\cdot m
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that that the right cancellation law holds:

If $y \cdot x = y' \cdot x$, then $y = (y \cdot x) \cdot x = (y' \cdot x) \cdot x = y'$.

Now given any elements $a$ and $b$, write

$$(a \cdot (b \cdot a))\cdot (b \cdot a) = a = b \cdot (b \cdot a)$$

Right-cancellation yields

$$a \cdot (b \cdot a) = b.$$

Now we have

$$ b \cdot a = a \cdot (a \cdot (b \cdot a)) = a \cdot b.$$